# I want parts of a scene to be invisible in final render but still be visible in reflections and light bounces

Tags: materials, compositing-nodes

I'm working on a scene in blender where I have recreated a corridor shot for real. In the scene, I have an object traveling down the corridor. The goal is to just get the object and not the corridor in the final render. I still want to get the reflections and light bounces of the corridor, maybe even shadows if possible!

I'm super new so I've been having a lot of problems. I've tried to use the Holdout node on the materials but that removes the light bounces. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **Shadow Catcher** feature available in versions 2.78.5 or higher. You don't need to do much.

Set the surrounding elements be a **shadow catcher** in Cycles Settings> Ray Visibility.

The rendered image will have the shadow and reflections and a transparent background.

[image]

Then just overlay the rendered image onto your background using Alpha Over:

[image]

---

For other ways to do this.

- Using a **Layer Mask**.

In this example the monkey is in layer 2 and the environment in layer 1. In the layer settings Layer 1 is used as a mask layer.

[image]

---

- Make the surrounding elements invisible to the camera using **Ray Visibility**.

[image]

---

- Make the surrounding elements use a material that is transparent to **Camera Ray** using Light Paths.

[image]

---

- Give the material for your object a Pass Index number, enable **Material Index** in the render layers, and use the Material Index as an ID mask to Set an alpha channel for the rendered image in the compositor.

[image]
(click on the image to enlarge)

---

- Give the Object a Pass Index number, enable **Object Index** in the render layers, and use the IndexOB as an ID mask to set an alpha channel for the rendered image in the compositor.

[image]

---