# How can I render only one object but still have the rest affecting it?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, render-layers

Is there any way in Blender to render only one object from a large scene but still have the rest of the objects affecting it ?

I need to change the material on a small piece but I don't want to render the rest of the scene again.

Comment: It is not going to be perfect, but you can render an HDR from from the object in questions point of view. see https://www.creativeshrimp.com/hdr-lighting-in-blender-part-6.html

Comment: You can restrict the vislibility to camera in all other objects, or use an object mask to subtract everything but the object from the rendered scene and composite on top. Read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48122/how-can-i-make-an-object-invisible-when-i-render-in-cycles

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102657/i-want-parts-of-a-scene-to-be-invisible-in-final-render-but-still-be-visible-in/102661#102661

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle object visibility at render:

[image]

Or play for each object with Cycles settings (here in 2.79):

[image]

**[EDIT]**

You can also render just a portion of the screen (CTRL-B on 2.79, then draw the box around your object) which can work mostly if your object doesn't move much in an animation.

For batching Cycles settings, I guess a python script would work, but that's above my current paygrade.

You can probably find an easy way to run through the objects list and set cycles_visibility.diffuse, cycles_visibility.camera, etc.

Comment: the first option it will just render the one i want but not affected by the other object so that doesnt do it for me. The second i think is the one that i need....Is there a way to mess with ray visibility for the whole collective ?

Comment: So first I had misunderstood. I thought that by "affected" you meant physics and stuff, but you mean shadows, reflections, etc. I will update my answer.